# Autolayout Resize UImageView and UILabel when UIImageView empty

Tags: uiimage, resize, autolayout, uilabel

When UIImageView is empty...than resize the UILabel and hidden the UIImageView.

[image]

Anyone a idea?

Comment: yes...use constant property of height constraints...or if you are using iOS9 use stackview

Answer (score 0):

1. You can either change label bottom constraint constant to either bottom spacing or image view top constraint - depending of visibility of image view or
2. (Available in iOS 8.0 and later.)
   Create two bottom NSLayoutConstraint for label. One with lower priority to bottom of the view and one with higher priority. Change active property to YES/NO of the one with higher priority depending of image view visibility